# How to get rid of Yaru theme and install Adwaita?

Tags: 22.04

I like Adwaita much more than Yaru theme for Ubuntu 22.04, but when I try to swap to the adwaita theme in gnome tweaks, it only gives me options for the various yaru themes and not adwaita.  This is specifically for the "shell" option.  The other options such as the icons lets me change it over.  How can I get rid of Yaru from my system, and find or install adwaita? Thank you. The forums won't let me put images in my post yet.

Comment: There is a dark adwaita theme here https://www.gnome-look.org/p/1827585